# Windows Media Player 11 and ID3v2.4 Support

Tags: windows-media-player, id3

It seems that Windows Media Player 11 won't read ID3v2.4 tags, either on windows xp or windows 7.
Is there a plugin that will the player to fetch ID3v2.4 data?

Comment: Have you looked for a plug-in?  What research have you done on this subject?  Would using VLC be a solution?

Comment: VLC is suitable for video media, less suitable for audio. I could use Winamp or iTunes, but I'd like to stick with WMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just convert the ID3v2.4 tags of your music files to ID3v2.3? I believe that [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) can do this. It's probably a good idea to make a backup of your music first.

The v2.4 format isn't implemented everywhere, while v2.3 tags has maximum compatibility.

Comment: because ID3V2.4 has more features that don't exist with IDv2.3. I suppose my best try would be changing a media player.

Comment: What kind of features? IDv2.3 already has an extensive list of supported tags.

Comment: You were right, the ID3v2.3 has everything that I need. The python lib that writes ID3 tags only supports v2.4 tags, but I found a way to make it work with v2.3 tags. It seems like the v2.4 format isn't implemented everywhere, while v2.3 tags has maximum compatibility.